Is my proof strategy faulty?
I am working on a proof that I am finding quite challenging. One particular step is making me uneasy.
Let $X,Y$ be arbitrary finite sets, and let $F=Y^X$ be the set of all functions $f:X\to Y$. My goal is to show that two axioms on $F$, called $A1$ and $A2$, imply a particular property, called $P2:$
\begin{gather}
A1\cap A2\Rightarrow P2.
\end{gather}
To show this,

I first show that $A1$ implies an intermediate property, called $P1$ $$A1\Rightarrow P1;$$
I then show that $A2$ and $P1$ imply the desired property $P2$ $$A2\cap P1\Rightarrow P2.$$

I can’t quite pinpoint why, it makes me uneasy that I know with certainty that $$P2\Rightarrow P1.$$
With the given information, is my proof valid?

The implication from $P2$ to $P1$ is not relevant to the work in writing an implication the other direction.  In some cases some of this work can be shared in both directions, but each direction stands on its own.

@abiessu Thank you very much for your comment. Then, as per your comment, I understand there is nothing inherently wrong with my proof strategy (at least, with the given information). Right?

From what I can see of your strategy, that is correct.

Your presentation is valid, because these statements are consistent with one another, because the negation of their conjunction is invalid:
\begin{gather}
A1\Rightarrow P1\\
(A2\land P1)\Rightarrow P2\\
P2\Rightarrow P1.
\end{gather}
